# Hyperledger Fabric Raft - In the configtx.yaml is there a way define a consenter set for each channel?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

The "Orderer" section of the configtx.yaml file has a "Consenters" tag that lists all the Raft nodes that form the ordering service. Is there a way to associate subsets of "Consenters" with individual channels?

Answer (score 0):

Consenter set

In a Raft ordering service, these are the ordering nodes actively participating in the consensus mechanism on a channel. If other ordering nodes exist on the system channel, but are not a part of a channel, they are not part of that channel’s consenter set.

So according to their [glossary documents](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/glossary.html) this is possible with channel’s consenter set.